# Losing messages with MQTT with C# uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt

Tags: c#, mqtt

I have a problem that I lose messages with MQTT although I send them with "QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE".

The loss is only when the receiver is not running and then starts later.
These messages are then not collected.

Version of M2Mqtt is 4.3.0

If both clients, i.e. receiver and transmitter, are running, no messages are lost.

Only if the receiver is not running, the messages are prefetched during this time and do not arrive at the receiver.

I can't find any setting on the server(broker) for how long messages should be saved

**sender**

```
public class Programm
{

    static MqttClient mqttClient;
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var locahlost = true;
        var clientName = "Sender 1";

        Console.WriteLine($"{clientName} Startet");

        var servr = locahlost ? "localhost" : "test.mosquitto.org";
        mqttClient = new MqttClient(servr);
        mqttClient.Connect(clientName);

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (mqttClient != null && mqttClient.IsConnected)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var Message = $"{clientName} ->Test {i}";
                    mqttClient.Publish("Application1/NEW_Message", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{Message}"), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, true);
                    Console.WriteLine(Message);
                    Thread.Sleep(i * 1000);
                }
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine($"{clientName} End");
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
public class Programm
{


    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server");
        MqttServerOptionsBuilder options = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
                                     // set endpoint to localhost
                                     .WithDefaultEndpoint()
                                     // port used will be 707
                                     .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1883);
        // handler for new connections



        // creates a new mqtt server     
        IMqttServer mqttServer = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer();

        // start the server with options  
        mqttServer.StartAsync(options.Build()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // keep application running until user press a key
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Receiver**

```
public class Programm
{
    static MqttClient mqttClient;


    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientName = "Emfänger 1";
        var locahlost = true;

        Console.WriteLine($"Start of {clientName}");
      

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var servr = locahlost ? "localhost" : "test.mosquitto.org";
            mqttClient = new MqttClient(servr);
            mqttClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += MqttClient_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
            mqttClient.Subscribe(new string[] { "Application1/NEW_Message" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
            mqttClient.Connect(clientName);
        });
        
        //  client.UseConnecedHandler(e=> {Console.WriteLine("Verbunden") });
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"end of  {clientName}");

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
    private static void MqttClient_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the default value for cleanSession in M2Mqtt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for the Clean session flag when connecting to the broker with M2MQTT is true.

This means that the broker will discard any queued messages.

https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/using-mqttclient/

You need to set this to false to ensure the client receives the queued messages.

```
 mqttClient.Connect(clientName, false);
```

Comment: I have changed the connection to   mqttClient.Connect(clientName, null, null, false, 60); but it does not work

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to start the subscriber first, then stop it and restart it for messages to be queued. The broker will NOT queue messages for a client it has not seen before.

Comment: Sometimes it does not work.
1. start server
2. start subscriber 
3. start sender

4. stop sender
Send 2-3 messages.

Only the last messages are transmitted.
The other ones do not arrive.

How long can the subscriber be offline?

Comment: The spec is indefinite, but really depends on the broker and how it's configured

Comment: I can't find any setting on the server(brocker) for how long messages should be saved

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, saving was missing.

Here is the new code from the server

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server");
    MqttServerOptionsBuilder options = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
                                 .WithDefaultEndpoint()
                                 .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1883)
                                 .WithConnectionValidator(OnNewConnection)
                                 .WithApplicationMessageInterceptor(OnNewMessage)
                                 .WithClientMessageQueueInterceptor(OnOut)
                                 .WithDefaultCommunicationTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                                 .WithMaxPendingMessagesPerClient(10)
                                 .WithPersistentSessions()
                                 .WithStorage(storage);
    // creates a new mqtt server     
    IMqttServer mqttServer = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer();
    // start the server with options  
    mqttServer.StartAsync(options.Build()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    // keep application running until user press a key
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You originally had an image embed in this post, but there was no URL, so it wasn’t showing up. I’ve removed the image embed. But if you want an image in this, you should [edit] your post, re-add it, and confirm that it was correctly embedded.